# rename NameSpace in reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces

when code tries to get the namespace name via reflection, using either:

```
typeof(MyNamespace.MyClass).Namespace;
```

or other methods, I want that the Namespace name returned my pre-defined string.

This doesn't work:

```
typeof(MyNamespace.MyClass).Namespace  = "helloWorld";
```

any ways?

p.s.  please don't post answers like : "Change namespace in source-code"...

Comment: `System.Type.Namespace` is _understandably_ a read-only property (i.e no setter).  I imagine changing namespaces at run time is impossible, it seems like an incredibly dangerous process (and I honestly cannot think of a use case right now)

Comment: `any ways?` Change the namespace in the source code.

Comment: I wonder what requirement has lead to this question.

Comment: yes, I have specific reason for that.. cant explain.

Comment: Use reflection.emit to build a new assembly and save to disk, with the new namespace in place.

Comment: @T.Todua Please try to explain your requirement.  This has all the trademarks of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and you might get better suggestions if we understand why you need to do this.

Comment: Touda, you as us, whet type of 'lens' *(pure = not coloured)* you should use to see that a blue car is yellow. What do you think is the answer? Or another way, how to use (Windows) calculator application, to copy video files from Youtube to your disk. When the application uses a namespace, it can be changed only by recompiling, or altering using some IL tools, but not at runtime. Even when it would be possible (with altering of memory), a antivirus solution would probably catch this attempt to change the running application code. It is not a good idea. The request is wrong, or badly understood

Comment: @Julo please post it as answer, i should upvote it

Answer (score 4):

Part of reflection API that deals with types and other assembly metadata is read-only. You can't change or influence any values returned by any of such calls (including namespace) - they simply read metadata of the assembly.

To achieve what you are asking you would need to change and recompile source code (either directly or after de-compiling IL) and rewrite namespaces before compilation.